# Java command prompt commands throw "No such File or Directory"

Tags: java, linux, console

I am currently working on a programm which should execute some console commands.

My code looks like this:

```
  private String executeCommands(String[] commands)
  {
    String result = "";
    try
    {
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
      String s = null;
      Charset charset = Charset.forName("IBM850");
      BufferedReader stdInput;
      Process proc;
      for (String command : commands)
      {
        System.out.println("Ausfuehrung von: " + command);
        pb.command(command);
        proc = pb.start();
        stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream(), charset));
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
        {
          result += s;
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      result = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
  }
  private void userLogIn(IUserInteraction userInteraction)
  {
    String[] command = { "svn auth --show-passwords" };
    String result = executeCommands(command);
    System.out.println(result);
  }
```

The output is "Cannot run program "svn auth --show-passwords": error=2, No such file or directory", but when i manually enter the command in the console, it works. What did i do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your code, are you running your command from the correct directory (same directory as when you run it manually)?

Comment: yes i do, both from /home/user

Comment: Is svn in your environment variable list? Try to print environment variables in java code and check if it is there.

Comment: @GurmeetGulati when i run java.util.Map<String, String> env = System.getenv(); the env  map contains null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries I found a working solution

```
String result
String line;
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      Reader r = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(r);
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;
      in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

`svn` means nothing for the jvm if environment variables are not carried to your application.

Try to execute the command with its full path:

```
String[] command = { "/bin/dir1/dir2/svn auth --show-passwords" };
```

If you don`t know where the program is, use the command below to figure it out:

```
which svn
```

Comment: the result of `which svn` was /usr/bin/svn. I added this to command but there is the same result